# I am looking for a union query to produce one total not two..ideas?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am not the greatest at writing SQL.  I wrote this in Access and then went to SQL view.  Took both queries and did a union all between them.  I keep getting a total from each query.  How do I get just one total for each product line.

```
Results:
Prod Line           Period             Amount
Cash Discounts  12            -1404010.46
CASH DISCOUNTS  12                1541.19
Freight           12               4050823.43
Freight           12                  6817.27
INK           12                -24467.76
INK           12                 44414.29

Want        
Cash discounts                          -1402469.27
Freight                                   405764.70
INK                                        24467.76
```

SQL

```
SELECT [JE Details].[Prod Line], [JE Details].Period, Sum([JE Details].Amount) AS Amount
FROM [JE Details]
GROUP BY [JE Details].[Prod Line], [JE Details].Period
HAVING ((([JE Details].Period)=12))
UNION ALL 
SELECT [AP Details].[Product Line], [AP Details].[Fiscal Period], Sum([AP Details].
[Invoice Amt]) AS Amount
FROM [AP Details]
GROUP BY [AP Details].[Product Line], [AP Details].[Fiscal Period]
HAVING ((([AP Details].[Fiscal Period])=12));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT [Prod Line], Sum(Amount) 
FROM 
   (SELECT [Prod Line], Amount
    FROM [JE Details] 
    WHERE Period=12
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Product Line] ,[Invoice Amt]
    FROM [AP Details] 
    WHERE [Fiscal Period]=12) q
GROUP BY [Product Line]
```